# XMLWorker custom margin for different pages

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to generate a PDF from an HTML, and after the PDF is generated, in a second step, add a watermark image on each page on the top left and some kind of reference on the top right.

This is however necessary only on the page 2...n-1. I have find a solution which is to have an higher top-margin in the first passage, and make it smaller on the second pass. However this works only if I make it on all the pages. Can I force the XMLWorker to use custom margins for every page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iText Page Events still work when using XmlWorker, so you could subclass PdfPageEventHelper and override the onStartPage() method to set the margins for the next page. Keep in mind that the margins have already been set for the first page, so setting those margins need to happen either by setting it yourself before opening the document or in the onOpenDocument() method (I haven't tested if this has any additional effects).

http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.html